# Get column1 values based on column2 in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to this webiste and SSRS.

I have data in the below format. I am getting below data from a procedure based on logged on user.

Empid       Field_Name
100         C_By
200         R_By
300         C_By
400         R_By
500         C-By

I would like to create a report parameter which accepts values from empid based on Filed_Name. ex: I want filter the data empid where Filed_Name='C_By' value.

Thanks & Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I read your question right but what I believe you asked is you have two parameters that one is dependent upon the other.

You can have cascading parameters.  What you need to do is to setup your EmpID parameter to use a data set for its available values and set the parameter for that data set equal to the value of the field_name parameter.

[Cascading Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If this is not what you need, you may want to rephrase your question.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Ariyana. I want to create and show user only empid parameter. I want to get empid value based on filed_name value. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are trying to filter your data set with EmployeeID as the parameter which then gets sent to your procedure, you will use the stored procedure or TSQL to use that EmpID to filter your dataset.  You cannot get the parameter values based upon a result set unless you have this as some sort of sub report but then you will have a parameter in the main report that is like Field Name.